# Java executes command but the value is not returned

Tags: java, linux, shell, runtime.exec

The PHP calls the shell script and the shell script calls the cronjob on the other server.

I am currently converting the same business logic into Java.

However, as we develop using Java's "Runtime", the cronjob of that server reports `(defunct)`

`WaitFor()` The web screen is also continuously waiting for the method

What should I do?

[image: screenshot]

```
public Map execCommand(String... str) {
    Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(str);
    pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
    Process process = null;
    try {
        process = pb.start();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    BufferedReader reader = null;
    if (process != null) {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
    }

    String line;
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        if (reader != null) {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                stringBuilder.append(line).append("\n");
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        if (process != null) {
            process.waitFor();
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (process != null) {
        map.put(0, String.valueOf(process.exitValue()));
    }

    try {
        map.put(1, stringBuilder.toString());
    } catch (StringIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        if (stringBuilder.toString().length() == 0) {
            return map;
        }
    }
    return map;
}
```

Comment: Could the output be going to stderr instead of stdout?

Answer (score 0):

Read from the input stream *after* `waitFor()`.